# Display All WooCommerce Variation Information on Product Page

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, product-variations

While this works fine as is, I need help in getting it to display all the different variation details that are available.

**As of now, it displays the price.** This is the full list of variables that are available:

```
'attributes'
'availability_html'
'backorders_allowed'
'dimensions'
'dimensions_html'
'display_price'
'display_regular_price'
'price'
'image'
'image_id'
'is_downloadable'
'is_in_stock'
'is_purchasable'
'is_sold_individually'
'is_virtual'
'max_qty'
'min_qty'
'price_html'
'sku'
'variation_description'
'variation_id'
'variation_is_active'
'variation_is_visible'
'weight'
'weight_html'
```

**This is the code** that I need help changing into displaying all of these as a table if at all possible.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'display_variation_info_in_product_summary' );
function display_variation_info_in_product_summary() {

   global $product;

            if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return;

                    echo '<div class="var_info"></div>';
                       wc_enqueue_js( "
                          $(document).on('found_variation', 'form.cart', function( event, variation ) {
                             $('.var_info').html(variation.price_html); // need to show all options here
                      });
               " );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

does this work? I'm using this to display a table of the variation options, with the price. It works with multiple attributes.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_variation_info_in_product_summary' );
function display_variation_info_in_product_summary() {
  global $product;

  if ( !$product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return;

  $variations = $product->get_available_variations();

  echo '<div class="variation-prices"><table>';
  foreach($variations as $variation){
    $attributes = wc_get_formatted_variation($variation['attributes'],true, false);
    echo '<tr><td>' . $attributes . '</td><td>' . wc_price($variation['display_price']) . '</td></tr>';
  }
  echo '</table></div>';
}
```